Uploading File Firebase - Efficiently
I am using this code to upload files to Firebase Storage but this code looks clunky and runs slowly. How can I improve the speed a file is stored to Firebase?
const uploadToStorage = async (uri: string, path: string, category: string, subcategory: string): Promise<string> => {
    try {
        const filename = `${Date.now()}-${Math.random().toString(36).substring(7)}.jpg`; // Unique filename
        const storageRef = ref(storage, `/${category}/${subcategory}/${filename}`);

        const response = await fetch(uri);
        const blob = await response.blob();

        const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, blob);

        return new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
            uploadTask.on('state_changed',
                (snapshot) => {
                    // Optional: Update progress to the user
                    const progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
                    console.log(`Upload is ${progress}% done`);
                },
                reject, // Handle unsuccessful uploads
                async () => {
                    try {
                        const downloadURL = await getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref);
                        resolve(downloadURL); // Resolve with the download URL
                    } catch (error) {
                        console.error(`Error getting download URL:`, error);
                        reject(error);
                    }
                }
            );
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error during the upload process", error);
        throw error;
    }
};

If I try something like this, it crashes my app the 2nd or 3rd time around. I need something reliable and works everytime but also can move in a decent speed.
const uploadToStorage = async (uri: string, path: string, category: string, subcategory: string): Promise<string> => {
    try {
        const filename = `${Date.now()}-${Math.random().toString(36).substring(7)}.jpg`; // Unique filename
        const storageRef = ref(storage, `/${category}/${subcategory}/${filename}`);

        const response = await fetch(uri);
        const blob = await response.blob();

        const uploadTask = uploadBytes(storageRef, blob);

        return new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
            uploadTask.then(
                async (snapshot) => {
                    const downloadURL = await getDownloadURL(snapshot.ref);
                    resolve(downloadURL);
                },
            ).catch((error) => {
                console.error("Error uploading image", error);
                reject(error);
            });
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error during the upload process", error);
        throw error;
    }
};


"it crashes my app the 2nd or 3rd time around"
Is there an error message?

UploadTask works just like a promise (because it has then and catch methods). You shouldn't have to wrap it in another promise.

Also, if you say something is slow here, you should provide your method of benchmarking.  Please show the code you're using to time the upload along with the results so we all know what's going on here.  Generally, you can't just write different code to improve the speed of an upload - it's always going to go as fast as your network connection will allow.

You say your code feels cluncky, but I can't see why? You setup your upload task, start it and return download URL when finished while handling errors.. Looks like OK to me.

This works for me:
    async function processUploadImage(uri, fileName, docId) {
        const response = await fetch(uri);
        const blob = await response.blob();
        const storageRef = ref(storage, `${id}/evidence${docId}/${fileName}`);
        const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, blob);

        uploadTask.on(
            "state_changed",
            (snapshot) => {
                const progress =
                    (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
                console.log("Loading..." + progress.toFixed() + "%");
            },
            (error) => {
                console.log("Error: ", error.serverResponse);
                setIsLoading(false);
                setCodeStorage("");
                setImage([]);
                setUrlData([]);
            },
            () => {
                getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then(async (downloadURL) => {
                    setUrlData((prevFiles) => [...prevFiles, { uri: downloadURL }]);
                });
            }
        );
    }

I am using expo imagepicker and when configuring it I opted for a medium image quality, so the images upload faster even if there are several of them:
let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
                mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
                allowsMultipleSelection: true,
                aspect: [4, 3],
                quality: 0.5,
                orderedSelection: true,
                selectionLimit: 20,
            });


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
